# Is there a Amazon S3 Bucket Policy equivalent in the Rackspace Cloudfiles?

Tags: rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

Is there a [Amazon S3 Bucket Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html) equivalent in Rackspace Cloudfiles? We would like to restrict access for certain containers to specific IP addresses. No other IP addresses should be able to access these cloudfile containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today there isn't, I literally just finished talking with techs there about this specifically thinking I was just missing it in the docs. And found out that they have no IP restrictions for protecting contents in containers.. don't know how they over-looked that one!

Answer (score 1):

no, there is no access restrictions based on IP or Host.